# Tag Merge Requests

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

[bootable](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bootable) - 29 questions tagged

[bootable-media](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bootable-media) - 84 questions tagged

---

[disk-utility](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disk-utility) - 82 questions tagged

[diskutility](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/diskutility) - (2) 0 questions tagged - retagged with above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
updating post history, 37 rows affected
updating posts, 32 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 27 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [bootable-media] and [bootable] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym bootable -> bootable-media was approved!
```

---

```
updating post history, 0 rows affected
updating posts, 0 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 0 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [disk-utility] and [diskutility] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym diskutility -> disk-utility was approved!
```

---

Done